# Bootable USB doesn't start installer

Tags: boot

I'm currently trying to do a clean installation of Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, reasons why being lackage of RAM due to motherboard limitations (max 8GB DDR2 800Mhz), the motherboard being the MS-7259 V1.1.

I created a bootable USB using Rufus as always, selecting FreeDOS as the desired boot selection, but when I try to boot up from the USB I get a FreeDOS screen asking the keyboard layout, then changing to a navigable filesystem of FreeDOS. I checked everything I knew about from the board, I made sure legacy USB was enabled (when it's disabled the USB is not recognizzed) and still nothing different will happen. I think the problem will be that my motherboard doesn't recognize UEFI, but honestly I don't know about it.

Could somebody help me? Or either recommend a Linux distro that has an App Store and minimun requirements be like 512MB of RAM, I'm trying to do this installation to help out a friend build a PC for his kids.

Comment: It's an Intel Dual Core 2.8GHz, I'm not sure of the reference. Yes, 8GB is plenty of RAM, but it's only 2GB available and I don't think they will be able to upgrade up to 8GB soon. The thing is, the motherboard itself is of 2005.

Comment: They still should be fine with Xubuntu or Lubuntu.  Both those requirements are like 128MB - 512MB at minimum.

Comment: I tried with Ubuntu 16.04 and happened the same. I don't think the problem resides in the edition I'm trying to install, but thanks.

Comment: See:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview as they don't use the FreeDOS.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#4-boot-selection-and-partition-scheme - It literally says use FreeDOS u_u

Comment: After step 5 it no longer says freedos but the version of Ubuntu that is being written.

Comment: I am running Lubuntu 18.04 on just 1.2GBs of ram.  12.04 has been out of support for years.  Ubuntu will install on older MBs easier than on a brand new MB.

Comment: Use Boot selection = Disk or ISO image, (Select the image). Partition scheme = MBR, Target system = BIOS or UEFI.